# GreaseMonkey Script, not parsing link added to DOM

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, greasemonkey

I am using a greasemonkey script namely Youtube Already: http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/47198

This script aims to highlight already visited links. The key factor is to strip out url params that invalidates a:visited.

```
i.e.: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKWPht3fU-o               != 
      http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKWPht3fU-o&featured=fvw
```

The important part is:

```
var cleanlink, dirtylink, i, x, aXpath;
aXpath = new Array(7);
aXpath[0] = '//a[contains(@href, "feature=related")]';
aXpath[1] = '//a[contains(@href, "feature=relmfu")]';
aXpath[2] = '//a[contains(@href, "feature=g-")]';
aXpath[3] = '//a[contains(@href, "feature=b-")]'; // &feature=b- all browse 
aXpath[4] = '//a[contains(@href, "/user/")]';
aXpath[5] = '//a[contains(@href, "/videos")]';    // search 
aXpath[6] = '//a[contains(@href, "&list")]';      // playlists

for(x in aXpath) {
    dirtylink = document.evaluate(aXpath[x], document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
    for (i = 0; i < dirtylink.snapshotLength; i++) {
        cleanlink = dirtylink.snapshotItem(i);
        switch (x){
        case 6:
                    cleanlink.href = cleanlink.href.replace(/\&feature(.*)/,"").replace(/\&index(.*)/,"");
            break;
        case 4:
        case 5:
            cleanlink.href = cleanlink.href.replace(/\?(.*)/,"");

            break;
        default :
            cleanlink.href = cleanlink.href.replace(/\&(.*)/,"");
                }
    }
}
```

The problem is taht this code will only check links in the standard HTML youtube page. The link added with AJAX (mostly on youtube channel) will not get normalized.

Is tehre any way to run this userscript even with AJAX-injected links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a direct way unless you want to run a timeout for your 'normalizer'

```
setInterval(function() {
    //> code here
},1000);
```

Comment: Acutally it is working, you made a mistake... setTimeout instead of setInterval :D

Comment: Oh sorry. I did mean setInterval. Brain didn't switch over from when I said "timeout" in the solution above

Comment: I have opened a topic on its main page: http://userscripts.org/scripts/discuss/47198